# Ubuntu startup time READ FPDMA error

Tags: ubuntu

For past one week my Ubuntu boot time has gone from 50sec approx to 5min.

I tried `dmesg` and the following message is shown multiple times in the log. How do I fix it?

```
[  101.186141] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x70 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
[  101.186148] ata1.00: irq_stat 0x40000008
[  101.186153] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
[  101.186167] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:20:f0:ab:18/00:00:64:00:00/40 tag 4 ncq 4096 in
                        res 41/40:00:f0:ab:18/00:00:64:00:00/40 Emask 0x409 (media error) <F>
[  101.186168] ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
[  101.186169] ata1.00: error: { UNC }


res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
    [  180.868343] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
    [  180.868344] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
    [  180.868346] ata1.00: cmd 60/f8:78:00:66:70/00:00:74:00:00/40 tag 15 ncq 126976 in
                            res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[180.868347] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[80.868348] ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
180.868351] ata1.00: cmd 60/08:80:80:a8:98/00:00:64:00:00/40 tag 16 ncq 4096 in
res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
```

smartmontools output

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-53-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M8 (AF)
Device Model:     ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB
Serial Number:    S2Y9J9AD713451
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0004cf 20aa6a576
Firmware Version: 2AR20002
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Thu Dec  8 17:38:07 2016 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (13380) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 223) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       1260
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0027   252   252   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   089   082   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       3454
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   068   068   000    Old_age   Always       -       32547
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   252   252   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   252   252   015    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6311
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   252   252   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       328
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       3027
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       5811877
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   252   252   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   252   252   048    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
186 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       728
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0002   062   049   040    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 19/51)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       209
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       124383
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   062   049   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 19/51)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       2
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9894

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1209         -
# 2  Short offline       Aborted by host               90%      1209         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Completed [00% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that drive is dying. I bet it makes odd crunchy noises, too. (It comes from the head moving repeatedly, as the drive tries to re-read data it cannot read without uncorrectable errors.)

As soon as you can, copy your personal files off that drive, and replace the drive. It may/will fail catastrophically soon, and then it won't work at all.

If the drive supports SMART and you have smartmontools installed, you could run `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda`, and report the results here. Based on the results, you could then run a long offline check (may take an hour or two, depending on the disk size) to find out exactly the state of the drive, but my bet, based on my experience, is it is dying. The only question is how fast it will fail completely.

Comment: I have added the smartmontool output as u mentioned.

Comment: The failure mode is not something I've seen before -- I usually see the raw value of attribute #5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct increasing as the performance degrades -- so I'm quite puzzled. @InQusitive, could you run `sudo smartctl -t offline /dev/sda`, `sudo smartctl -t short /dev/sda`, or `smartctl -t long /dev/sda` -- they are in increasing order of time you need to wait in between! -- followed by `smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda` to see the self test status (and `smartctl -a /dev/sda` after the offline test, since it gathers offline statistics)?